# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS stopped working overnight. I/O error and COMRESET failed (errno=-16)

Tags: io

Yesterday night, I installed Ubuntu, it was working fine that night. Today morning I opened my laptop for my class, it was working fine, but after some time my class got struck. And it opened CLI(command line interface) and in some text, it showed I/O error. So, I though a restart of he computer would be a quick fix, but when I restarted, It opened CLI again and it showed COMRESET failed (errno=-16).
I still have the bootable drive, so if you want me to do something with it, I can do anything with it like reinstall, or anything else what you would recommend to solve the problem.
I tried to re-install ubuntu 20.04 LTS but it showed me an error that it is getting an I/O error. But, it is working fine when I am in trying mode.
Please say something, what can I do to fix it, I need to fix it fast!

(And also to mention, my laptop had a little accident, when I was holding my laptop and moving to a room, it fell on a bed, not too far in height, not too near, it fell from a distance of about 30cm)

Comment: It your notebook has a spinning disk hard drive, a “30cm” fall can be fatal if the read/write arms could not be seated before hitting the bed and bouncing numerous times.

Comment: Run **GSmartControl** to check your disk(s) status. If there are logged errors and the disk(s) do not pass the tests, you need to replace the disk(s) ASAP.

Comment: Matigo, it may be what you are saying, but is there any way to fix it. I used windows 10 before installing ubuntu. And it didn't bounce(or maybe, I didn't see properly)

Comment: Do you still have Windows installed? If so try booting it and you'll likely see problems as well. An I/O error during installation is pretty much diagnostic of a broken drive. Replace it.

Comment: I've replaced my old HDD with a new SSD and its now working good, and better than ever. If not for this website, I would have never known that I needed to replace the hard drive. SDD is better but has its own limitations, like not as much as storage for the same price (my old storage was 1TB and the new one is 512GB, 50% less) I kinda hate it but dont care much about it.